# Replace ftime() system call in linux with a suitable system call

Tags: c++, linux

Replace ftime() system call has become obsolete. I need  a  suitable system call to get the time in milliseconds. I was able to find time(), gettimeofday(). But these doesn't fit into my requirement as i want the return time to be in precise milliseconds. 
Can someone suggest me the suitable system call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it has to be a system call or you can't use C++11 (for `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`), you could probably use `clock_gettime(3)`.

Comment: See also [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) for a good overview.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: nice summary and comparison, bookmarked it.  I should look at section 7 more often :)

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
auto timepoint std::chrono::system_clock::now();
auto since_epoch =  timepoint.time_since_epoch()
auto milliseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(since_epoch) // epoch is implementation specific
std::cout << "Time in milliseconds: ";
std::cout << milliseconds.count() << '/n';
```

?